# monetdbe: multiple connections reading vs writing

Tags: monetdb

I am finding that with `monetdbe` (embedded, Python), I can import data to two tables simultaneously from two processes, but I can't do two `SELECT` queries.

For example, if I run this in Bash:

```
(python stdinquery.py < sql_examples/wind.sql &); (python stdinquery.py < sql_examples/first_event_by_day.sql &)
```

then I get this error from one process, while the other finishes its query fine:

```
monetdbe.exceptions.OperationalError: Failed to open database: MALException:monetdbe.monetdbe_startup:GDKinit() failed (code -2)
```

I'm a little surprised that it can write two tables at once but not read two tables at once. Am I overlooking something?

My `stdinquery.py` is just:

```
import sys
import monetdbe

monet_conn = monetdbe.connect("dw.db")
cursor = monet_conn.cursor()
query = sys.stdin.read()
cursor.executescript(query)
print(cursor.fetchdf())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are starting multiple concurrent Python processes. Each of those tries to create or open a database on disk at the `dw.db` location. That won't work because the embedded database *processes* are not aware of each others.

With the core C library of monetdbe, it is possible to write multi-threaded applications where each connecting application thread uses its own connection object. See this example written in C [here](https://github.com/MonetDBSolutions/monetdbe-examples/blob/master/C/concurrent.c). Again this only works for concurrent threads within a single monetdbe process, not multiple concurrent monetdbe processes claiming the same database location.

Unfortunately it is not currently possible with the  Python `monetdbe` module to setup something analogous to the C example above. But probably in the next release
it is going to be possible to use e.g. `concurrent.futures` to write something similar in Python.

Comment: Thanks - I was confused because I was "able" to write from 2 concurrent processes but not read. But, it turns out that my scripts weren't actually reaching the relevant steps at the same time, and it indeed raises the same error when they actually overlap.